# Installing 64 bit pygame to work with 64 bit kivy

Tags: python, pygame, kivy

I'm trying to use kivy on my Macbook Pro running 10.12.1. The kivy version I have installed is 64 bit, but the pygame version is 32 bit, so when I run a basic kivy program I get returned this error:

```
    pygame - ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SDL_EnableUNICODE
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/text/text_pygame.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
```

What is the workaround for this? I've got a bunch of 64 bit modules I want to use so don't want to switch entirely to 32 bit python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Kivy's pygame support is long deprecated, although it probably still does work. Instead you should use SDL2 - this should be done automatically if you follow the [Kivy install instructions](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html#using-homebrew-with-pip).

Answer (score 0):

> The kivy version I have installed is 64 bit, but the pygame version is
>   32 bit

You can't arbitrarily choose bitness of module. You should find and install module with same bitness as CPython interpreter you use has.

Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/audreyr/5943575#check-for-problems-with-your-pygame-installation) article and solution it provides.